# Swagger UI shows a wrong status code for a JAX-RS resource

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, http-status-codes, swagger-ui, doclet

I have a very simple delete method:

```
/**
 * Delete the question with the specified id
 *
 * @return a <code>204 NO CONTENT</code> on success or a <code>404 NOT FOUND</code> if there is no question available
 * @successResponse 204 The question was successfully deleted
 * @errorResponse 404 The question does not exist
 */
@DELETE
public Response delete(@PathParam("questionId") final Long questionId) {
    final Question question = findByQuestionId(questionId); // throws NotFoundException
    questionService.delete(question.getQuestionId());
    return Response.noContent().build();
}
```

As you can see, I used JavaDoc tags to specify the success and error response codes. Inside the method I create a no content response (which is a status code of 204). This is what swagger-doclet generates:

```
{
  "method" : "DELETE",
  "nickname" : "delete",
  "type" : "Response",
  "parameters" : [ {
    "type" : "integer",
    "format" : "int64",
    "paramType" : "path",
    "name" : "questionId",
    "required" : true
  } ],
  "summary" : "Delete the question with the specified id",
  "responseMessages" : [ {
    "code" : 204,
    "message" : "The question was successfully deleted"
  }, {
    "code" : 404,
    "message" : "The question does not exist"
  } ],
  "produces" : [ "application/json" ]
}
```

So far, so good: It takes my JavaDoc tags with the success and error response codes. In addition, there is a type "Response" which seems to be taken from methods return statement. Now, when I open Swagger UI, I got the following view:

[image]

At the top you can see "Response Class (Status 200)" where "Response Class" is correct but "Status 200" is wrong! Nowhere in this method I return a status code of 200 (OK). I did not find any working solution to correct this output.

What I use:

- Java 8
- Maven 3.3.9
- Dropwizard 0.9.2
- org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-javadoc-plugin 2.10.3
- com.tenxerconsulting.swagger-doclet 1.1.3

If you want to try it out, the complete project is on GitHub: https://github.com/McPringle/moodini

It would be really great to get a correct swagger API documentation. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is rendered by swagger-ui automatically.

Did you try @ApiResponses with nested @ApiResponse ?

```
/**
 * Delete the question with the specified id
 *
 * @return a <code>204 NO CONTENT</code> on success or a <code>404 NOT FOUND</code> if there is no question available
 */
@ApiResponses(value = { 
      @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "The question was successfully deleted"),
      @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The question does not exist")
})
@DELETE
public Response delete(@PathParam("questionId") final Long questionId) {
    final Question question = findByQuestionId(questionId); // throws NotFoundException
    questionService.delete(question.getQuestionId());
    return Response.noContent().build();
}
```

edit: full docu here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apiresponses-apiresponse

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, but it does not work. There is still no response information in the JSON file:
`{
      "method" : "DELETE",
      "nickname" : "delete",
      "type" : "Response",
      "parameters" : [ {
        "type" : "integer",
        "format" : "int64",
        "paramType" : "path",
        "name" : "questionId",
        "required" : true
      } ],
      "summary" : "Delete the question with the specified id",
      "produces" : [ "application/json" ]
    }`

Comment: you might try another plugin: https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin

it generates also a static JSON-file during maven-compile.
and it also support Swagger-Spec 2.0 and has more gh-stars etc.